# Select audio track to use when generating a waveform image

Tags: ffmpeg, waveform

ffmpeg can draw a waveform with `showwavespic` which works fine. But in my case, I have a file with multiple audio tracks and I want to specify which audio track to use to draw the waveform.
The default example is: `ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120" -frames:v 1 output.png`
I tried to add a `map 0:a:0` inbetween but that gives strange ffmpeg errors.
Does anybody know how I can set the track index to use without first extracting the desired audiotrack?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using filtergraph link labels (see https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1) to select the relevant input eg:

`ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:a:6]showwavespic=s=640x240" -frames:v 1 output.png`